# Bring to front a window from system()

Tags: php, shell, cmd

I've a piece of code which opens Windows Explorer and Windows Time and Date:

```
system('explorer');
```

And

```
system('timedate.cpl');
```

The only problem is that sometimes it  opens the windows behind the current window and I would like to bring it in front of any other window. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternate ways of opening applications :

`system('start timedate.cpl');`

`system('cmd /k timedate.cpl');`

Not sure if you can really control the focus of a window the way that you're launching it.